# Independence of Jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm doing unit testing with React, and we use jest for unit testing. We have `"jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3" in devDependencies and "jest": {"collectCoverageFrom": [(insert directories)]}` in our package.json file.

My question is: in the absence of any further configurations set, are the tests truly run independently of one another? I want to ensure that running one test.js file has NO effect on running another test.js file.

The reason I am asking this is because I have a `Component.test.js` that tests for a `Component.js` file, and within that file, I have the lines `delete window.location` and `window.location = {reload: jest.fn()};`, due to the fact that in the `Component.js` file I am actually doing window.location.reload, which does not exist in Jest's Node.js environment and therefore has to be mocked. I fear that setting `window.location = {reload: jest.fn()};` will also affect other files being tested.

Any help is appreciated. I find `"clearMocks": true, "resetMocks": true, "resetModules": true` to be quite promising to set in package.json.

Comment: Jest provides separate environments for your test **files**. If you have multiple tests in the same file you can restore the global overrides in the [teardown](https://jestjs.io/docs/setup-teardown) hooks.

Comment: Oh, excellent. So let's say I set `window.location = {reload: jest.fn()};` in one `test.js` file and forgot to clean it up; another `test.js` file is not affected by this right? Or alternatively, let's say that I mocked the `useState` hook through `React.useState = jest.fn(...)` in one `test.js` file and forgot to clean it up; this won't affect the value of `React.useState` in another `test.js` right?

Comment: That sounds correct to me. Set up an example and test it though.